# High end video card upgrade

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I would like to know if this motherboard can support a high end video card like AMD R9 390, my full system is:

- CPU :Intel Core i5 760 2.80GHz
- MB: Gigabyte GA-P55A-UD3 v1.0
- Memory: DDR3 Geil Enhance CORSA DUAL CHANNEL 2x4GB
- Cooler: Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO
- GPU: Powercolor HD6870x2
- HDD: Western Digital Black 1TB 7200 SATA-III and Toshiba 2TB SATA-III 7200RPM 64MB
- Case: Recom PowerStation Evo black
- PSU: Seasonic SS-850HT 850W (refurbished)

Comment: As you can see this is not the kind of question SU is made for, but at least I can tell you that YES, you can use that AMD graphics card in your existing setup. In fact, you can use any PCI-e 16x 1.0/2.0/3.0 graphics card you like.  Have fun ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're removing the old graphics.

Power supply is adequate, motherboard has the necessary PCI-E x16 slot. Make sure your case can fit the card - AMD cards tend to be physically large - and that you have decent cooling (the card itself will have a lot, but it could block airflow to elsewhere if the case has bad ventilation), but otherwise that's a pretty good setup. If you could run a 6870x2, the 930 should have no trouble.

If you want to leave both graphics cards installed, you may have trouble. Make sure your power supply can support that many demanding PCIe cards - both graphics cards will need much more power than they can pull through the PCIe bus - and that your motherboard's PCIe x16 slots are far enough apart that both cards can get good airflow (given the width of these cards, that typically means there should be at least three slots between the cards). You're probably still OK, though, if your cooling is up to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry if my post caused trouble but I'm in doubt, I have only one video card with two GPU (Powercolor HD6870x2) and I want to upgrade it with a powerful one, the doubt was if I should change my platform first with Skylake.